# Run command from context menu without showing console

Tags: windows, windows-registry, context-menu, console

I'm trying to add a context menu entry that will open a file for edit in Perforce. It works, but I'm wondering if there's a way to execute the command without briefly showing the command window. Here's what I have:

```
HKCU
    Software
        Classes
            *
                shell
                    p4
                        (Default) = Open file for edit in Perforce
                        command
                            (Default) = C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe edit "%1"
```

Comment: What does the cmd window show as it's contents?

Comment: @DavidPostill it shows the command.

Answer (score -1):

How about running a batch file silently through your context menu using one of the following methods:
https://www.raymond.cc/blog/hidden-start-runs-batch-files-silently-without-flickering-console/

such as Hidden Start, as there is an option to hide console window:

[image: Hidden Start]

[download Hidden Start here](https://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html)

Another free option would be NirCMD. The exec and hide commands are used to run the script or batch file and hide any console from opening.

One just use elevatecmd if you require administrator privileges for the batch file.

[image]

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html (website)

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.zip  (download x32)

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd-x64.zip (download x64)

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html#using (helpfile)

Otherwise please read more options here: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/hidden-start-runs-batch-files-silently-without-flickering-console/

Hope this help!